# Informatica extract value between the

Tags: informatica-data-integration-hub

I am having data like swathi|reddy|deka i need to extract the data between the pipes i. e reddy using expression transformation in informatica

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, unfortunately this question does not provide any codes so its not possible for us to help you with this, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us what problems you are facing while attempting to do this, And also don't forget to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on how to ask a good question and what type of questions are [well suited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 0):

You can use [REG_EXTRACT](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/transformation-language-reference/functions/reg_extract.html)

> REG_EXTRACT(my_column, '(\w+)|(\w+)|(w+)', 2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The above expression is not getting populated correctly. In the output it is showing error or null